# Graph explorer C# snippets do not work with Microsoft.Graph" Version="5.9.0"

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

To get just selected fields, I test in Graph explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/372ddaf5-60a1-46d4-bb19-2f80c9ba32b3/lists/DPC-Job-Master/items?expand=fields(select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)&$filter=fields/Completion gt '2023-05-04T09:15:32.6473018Z' and fields/CurrentQueue eq 'Done' and fields/DoneReceived eq null
```

it works fine. the snippet is:

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "fields(select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "fields/Completion gt '2023-05-04T09:15:32.6473018Z' and fields/CurrentQueue eq 'Done' and fields/DoneReceived eq null";
});
```

When using the snippet in my code it failes with:

```
"Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Term '(select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)' is not valid in a $select or $expand expression."

Is there a better way to figure out the syntax that will work?
Thank you
```

Comment: If you use nested select keyword within the expand parameter, the `$` must be used in all or nothing. The SDK uses the `$` and you have to use it too. So you have to write `fields($select=Title,...)`

Comment: Thank you that did it. I whish the snippets would show it too.

Comment: Already opened an issue: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/20678

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to get request information and check what url is generated by 5.9.0

```
var request = graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items.ToGetRequestInformation((requestConfiguration) =>
            {
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "fields(select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)" };
                requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "fields/Completion gt '2023-05-04T09:15:32.6473018Z' and fields/CurrentQueue eq 'Done' and fields/DoneReceived eq null";
            });
```

`result.URI.AbsoluteUri` has the value

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items?%24filter=fields%2FCompletion%20gt%20%272023-05-04T09%3A15%3A32.6473018Z%27%20and%20fields%2FCurrentQueue%20eq%20%27Done%27%20and%20fields%2FDoneReceived%20eq%20null&%24expand=fields%28select%3DTitle%2CRequestForLookupId%2CCompletion%2CCurrentQueue%2CDoneReceived%29
```

Decoded

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$filter=fields/Completion gt '2023-05-04T09:15:32.6473018Z' and fields/CurrentQueue eq 'Done' and fields/DoneReceived eq null&$expand=fields(select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)
```

You can see that SDK generates `$expand` instead of `expand`.

As a quick fix you can use `$select` inside Expand:

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites["{site-id}"].Lists["{list-id}"].Items.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    // $select instead of select
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string []{ "fields($select=Title,RequestForLookupId,Completion,CurrentQueue,DoneReceived)" };
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "fields/Completion gt '2023-05-04T09:15:32.6473018Z' and fields/CurrentQueue eq 'Done' and fields/DoneReceived eq null";
});
```